# SELECT if 2 cells in a row are equal

Tags: mysql, sql

Tried to show it as simple as possible. 
I want to SELECT Subject if 2 cells in a row are equal

Table

```
---------------------------------------------
Subject  ---  username  --- Lastpostername 
---------------------------------------------
subject A --- user1    ---  user3
Subject B --- user2    ---  user3
Subject C --- user3    ---  user3
Subject D --- user4    ---  user1
```

Result I need is to select subject C cause username and lastpostername are equal
(Sorted DESC by ID, so newest comes first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.subject
FROM tab AS t
WHERE t.username = t.Lastpostername
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Comment: Wow. It was so simple. I was trying with LEFT JOIN same table or SELECT statement within a SELECT query. ... Sometimes I am just thinking too difficult

Answer (score 1):

suppose your table name is 'abc' & then you can create bellow query,

```
SELECT Subject from abc WHERE abc.username = abc.Lastpostername ORDER BY abc.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```mysql
SELECT Subject from Table WHERE username = Lastpostername ORDER BY id desc;
```